# Can't delete remote tag

Tags: git

I added a tag too early and now want to remove it.

I have removed the local tag.

Now trying to do the remote:

```
$ git push origin :refs/tags/v17.1.8
```

Fails:

```
ajtru@DESKTOP-4OHL3UQ MINGW64 /d/My Programs/2017/MeetSchedAssist (master)
$ git push origin :refs/tags/v17.1.8
Warning: Permanently added the RSA host key for IP address '104.192.143.1' to the list of known hosts.
Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

Comment: Your problem has nothing to do with tags but with the fact that you don't have access rights to the remote

Comment: @NilsWerner Using TortoiseGit I can push to my repository. So what step must I take with "Git" then?

Answer (score 0):

You have to set up your ssh keys to access the repository.

#### Check to see if you have ssh keys

```
# open git-bash and type this:
cat ~/.ssh/id_sra.pub
```

If nothing is printed so you don't have any keys.

#### Set yous ssh keys

```
# open git-bash and type this:
ssh-keygen
```

follow the instruction on the screen and create your keys and once its there copy them and set them under your profile of your git serevr

```
# in git-bash
cat ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub

# copy the key with the ssh-... until the end and set it under your git server
```

Once you set up your keys test the connection using the `fetch` command

```
# test that you can access the repository
# if there is no error message than all is fine
git fetch --all -prune
```

Comment: I have those keys already. What I needed to do was add the path to the tortoisegitplink software to my computer environment variables. Then it worked. I indicated that question in my comment to my question.